# Allow contributor user role to perform copy operation PHP

Tags: plugin-development, user-roles, capabilities

I have posted the issue on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65898091/wordpress-allow-contributor-user-role-to-perform-copy-operation-php) but didn't get any solution. So now I am posting here. I want to allow contributor user role can copy file from one location to another location. I am using `copy(copy_from, copy_to)` function. The issue is that when this function executes, I am getting PHP warning of `failed to open stream: Permission denied`. The same function works fine when logged in as administrator user role. I tried to add capability of `manage_options` to the user so that contributor can also copy the files. But the `add_cap()` returns nothing and not adding capability to the user.

Here is the code I am using

```
function fn_add_cap($cap)
{
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $userID = $current_user->ID;
    $user = new WP_User($userID);
    $user->add_cap( $cap );
}

function fn_remove_cap($cap)
{
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $userID = $current_user->ID;
    $user = new WP_User($userID);
    $user->remove_cap( $cap );
}


$assigned_cap = 0;
if(!current_user_can('manage_options')){
    fn_add_cap('manage_options');
    $assigned_cap = 1;
}

$copy_from : 'C:\xamp\htdocs\wordpress\themes\twentytwelve\page.php';
$copy_to = 'C:\xamp\htdocs\wordpress\themes\twentytwelve-child\page.php';
$coppied = copy($copy_from, $copy_to);
if($coppied){
    echo "file coppied";
} else{
    echo "not coppied";
}

if($assigned_cap == 1){
    fn_remove_cap('manage_options');
}
```

Can anyone help me where I am doing wrong or any other alternative to get it working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: WordPress user roles and capabilities do nothing to control access to core PHP functions. That's not what they're for. You need to elaborate on what your code is for and when it runs. For example, what are `$copy_from` and `$copy_to`?

Comment: The code is to allow staff members (contributor) to copy files from one directory to another. `$copy_from` and `$copy_to` is the absolute path of the file that needs to be copied and `$copy_to` is the absolute path of the file where the file needs to be copied. i.e. `$copy_from : 'C:\xamp\htdocs\wordpress\themes\twentytwelve\page.php';` and `$copy_to = 'C:\xamp\htdocs\wordpress\themes\twentytwelve-child\page.php';`

Comment: "xamp" or "xampp" - just asking? Perhaps you can use a function to build the paths to be sure..

Comment: Its xamp. I am passing the file name on click of the list. I am creating url dynamic using wp function.